# Very weird Date behaviour by PHP/MySQL and iOS

Tags: php, ios, date, isset

I'm porting my Android app to iOS and I'm at the chat stage.

Each message has its own date, and my server API (in PHP) has a method that fetches all messages since a date (so I can send a request with my `lastMessageDate` and get any new messages that are not on the device whenever needed)

My database is MySQL and the server's timezone is GMT+2. The DB saves all dates as GMT+2, and PHP sends them as string back to the client.

In Android, and in my REST client for testing, calling the following request gives the "No new messages" message, as it should:
[image: works as expected]

In iOS, since the OS translates all Dates to UTC, before sending the date, I turn in into a GMT+2 string. I've been testing and debugging this date string, and it is indeed in GMT+2, as my server expects it to be.
Printing with the debugger the POST params before sending the request, shows that the time is indeed in GMT+2:

`Params: ["since": "2017-03-15 21:16:04", "chat_id": "86", "username": "testuser"]`

However, sending the exact same request, as in my REST client, returns chat messages that have been posted the past 2 hours, like if the iOS app is sending the UTC date instead of my GMT+2 string.

The response in the iOS emulator is the following:

```
Received data is: 
{
  "message" : "Messages in this chat:",
  "messages" : [
    {
      "message" : "This is a message",
      "chat_id" : "86",
      "who" : "1",
      "date" : "2017-03-15 21:16:04"
    }
  ],
  "error" : false
}
```

I've been trying to debug this for the past 4 hours with no luck. I don't know if it's the server's fault or iOS' fault, so if anyone can point me to the right direction, it would be very much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Nowhere do you show how you use the date that would cause this problem. And where is the PHP, MySql and Android?

Comment: Sorry for not posting more code, but I don't think it's necessary, since 2 out of 3 platforms are working. For iOS requests I'm using Alamofire and the params I have in my question are the dictionary that iOS is sending to the server. After more debugging I think that the problem is within PHP. It is not getting the "since" parameter when the request is sent from iOS.

I'm trying to get the POST param with: `if (filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'since')) { $since = $reqData['since']; }` but when the request is sent from iOS `$since` is null on the server. Any ideas?
In PHP I use SLIM framework.

Comment: `$reqData is an array with POST parameters returned by the SLIM framework using `$reqData = $req->getParsedBody();`

Comment: You need to show some iOS code, if you suspect that that is where the problem is.  As an aside, and it is probably too late now, as you have other platforms, but you should store your dates on the server as UTC, then it is simple for all clients to use UTC dates rather than having to adjust to some arbitrary timezone.

Comment: do you log what the server receives as request and what does it send back as response? do it, so at least, you'll know on which side the problem is.

Comment: After more debugging and logging, it seems like when the request comes form iOS, PHP always returns `false` for `isset $_POST['since']` and `filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'since')`

Still trying to figure out why. When the request comes from the REST client, or android it works as expected. Could iOS be encoding the param names in a way isset/PHP is not reading them? (I can grab the parameters, but I can't test if they exist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I need to encode the request with `Alamofire.URLEncoding.httpBody` instead of `Alamofire.JSONEncoding.default` in order for PHP to be able to check for parameters using `isset($_POST["since"])`. I didn't face this problem before, in the other 40 API calls that my app encodes with `Alamofire.JSONEncoding.default`.

If anyone can explain when it's best to encode using URLEncoding and when JSONEncoding, let me know.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help!